# I want to take input of an integer 2D array in matrix form. To take the first row elements separated by space and so on

Tags: c

I need to take input as:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
```

and so on.

This is what I have been trying -

```
for(k = 0; k < n; k++)
    while(scanf("%d", &a[k][i++]) == 1);
```

Comment: And you don't like the result? Why? Where do you get stuck? What happens unexpectedly? What does not happen though expected to happen? What is in the input stream when things stop working as expected?

Comment: Please study and apply the concept of a [mcve].

Comment: The inner loop doesn't terminate until EOF (or a non-numeric character in the input), so you run out of bounds of your array swiftly.  You should probably be using two `for` loops.  If the matrices are square, both loops run to the same limit.  If the matrix is 3 rows by 4 columns, then you need to know that ahead of time.  Or you need to read the first line into a string, determine how many numbers are in it, and allocate space for matrices, etc.  But I suspect that dynamically allocated matrices are not something you can handle yet.  It would be good if you created an MCVE ([MCVE])!

Answer (score 0):

You should reset the `i` index at each iteration of the outer loop and stop at the number of columns in the destination matrix. Here is a modified version with 2 `for` loops:

```
int a[n][m];
int i, k;
for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &a[k][i]) != 1) {
            // handle conversion error
        }
    }
}
```